# Effective Address Time in two level paging

Tags: caching, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, tlb

I am currently working on some project on OS, I know how to find EAT in single level paging which is

`EAT = (MAT+TLB-AT)*a+(2*MAT+TLB-AT)*(1-a)`

where

```
MAT is memory access time, 
TLB-AT is TLB hit time
a is hit ratio
```

I am trying to find out `EAT` in two levels, will it access memory 3-times in case of TLB-miss or four.

Comment: Is [this link](http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~hilzer/csci152/htm/EAT-TLB.htm) helpful for you?

Comment: Thank you so much brother, that helped me. kindly post it as answer so I accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there is a hit in TLB ==> We require  **{TLB access time + Access time for actual page from memory}**

When there is miss in TLB ==> We require **{TLB Access time + Access time for page table entry from memory +  Access time for actual page from memory}**

**For 1-Level Paging** ==> Access time for page table entry from memory

**For 2-Level Paging** ==> 2 * Access time for page table entry from memory

**.
.**

**For n -Level Paging** ==> n * Access time for page table entry from memory

So the generalized formula can be:

EMAT= p * (TLB-Access-time + Memory Access time) + (1-p) *[TLB-Access-time +((n+1) *Memory Access time)]

Here, p=hit ratio.

Answer (score 3):

EAT = (%hit)(TLBAT + MAT) + (1-%hit)(TLBAT + (n+1)(MAT))

Since we have to go to memory twice for single level paging, when we add another page to the mix it simply adds one more memory read to the process.